# CountDownTimer problem when app is closed

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I made a CountDownTimer code, I would like the CountDownTimer to restart when it is finished even if the app is closed, but it only restarts if the app is running or when the app is re-launched. So if I close the app when the countdown is 00:10 (min: sec) and reopen the app after 30 sec, the counter should be 00:40, but it starts from 1 minute... But if I close the app at 00:40 and reopen it after 10 sec, it starts at 00:30 so it's good, but the problem is that it restarts from 1 min when the app closed and reopened.... can somebody help me?

My code:

```
package com.example.countdown_implement;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 60000;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private long mEndTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

}

private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //mTimerRunning = false;
            //updateButtons();

            updateCountDownText();
            resetTimer();
            startTimer();

        }
    }.start();

    //mTimerRunning = true;

}


private void resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateCountDownText();

}

private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);

    editor.apply();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

    updateCountDownText();
    startTimer();
    if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
        updateCountDownText();
        startTimer();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**Below is your code converted into a code snippet for a CountdownTimer which will keep working even when the app is closed, pushed to background or restarted.**

set `START_TIME_IN_MILLIS` as the Timer start time, in the following example it is set to 15 seconds.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 15000;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private long mEndTime;
    private long remainingTimeInMillis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(remainingTimeInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                remainingTimeInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //mTimerRunning = false;
                //updateButtons();

                updateCountDownText();
                resetTimer();
                startTimer();

            }
        }.start();

        //mTimerRunning = true;

    }


    private void resetTimer() {
        remainingTimeInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();

    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {


        int minutes = (int) (remainingTimeInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (remainingTimeInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.apply();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
        mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        if (mEndTime == 0L) {
            remainingTimeInMillis = (mTimeLeftInMillis);
        } else {
            Long timeDiff = (mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
            //to convert into positive number
            timeDiff = Math.abs(timeDiff);

            long timeDiffInSeconds = (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
           long timeDiffInMillis = timeDiffInSeconds * 1000;
            Long timeDiffInMillisPlusTimerRemaining = remainingTimeInMillis = mTimeLeftInMillis - timeDiffInMillis;

            if (timeDiffInMillisPlusTimerRemaining < 0) {
                timeDiffInMillisPlusTimerRemaining = Math.abs(timeDiffInMillisPlusTimerRemaining);
                remainingTimeInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS - timeDiffInMillisPlusTimerRemaining;
            }
        }
        updateCountDownText();
        startTimer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to do foreground service without notification? I would like to make idle game, but i see some other similar games are not do notification, like "Simcity buildit"  or "Holiday city"  etc... just close app, and timers running without any notification.

Comment: If games can do it, so can you :). Actually we overcomplicated the problem. Updated answer contains the working solution. you dont need any kind of services for that.

Comment: Actually you were not calculating the time difference correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works very good :) You helped me a lot, sorry but i'm new member and i can't give rep, but i will do, and i will give you some $$$ when my game will be published. :) Thanks again. I will analize the new code what you gived me, and try to learn. Thanks

Comment: Did it. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210535/discussion-between-usman-zafer-and-joska).

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look here: [Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

You need `onResume`, `onPause` and `onDestroy` so that all scenarios are covered.

For `onResume`, the reason is, when you put your app to `background`, and resume the app by making it to `foreground`, action can be further applied, for example, getting the last saved state from SharedPreferences to ensure the condition is executed.

For `onPause`, it is crucial because when you click your phone home button, this state will be executed. Therefore, it ensures all the states is saved before it is destroyed (insurance).

For `onDestroy`, it is the most crucial part, because for some low-end phones, resources are limited, the os will do the 'cleaning' by killing apps, so for your app, it will get kill, so before it is killed, you can save the state.

Hence, whenever you start or use your app, query the `SharedPreferences`, and do some calculation to ensure everything is correct.

Use `service` or `broadcast`, which allow your program to run background.

Some detailed explanation from the documentation:

1. `onResume()`

When the activity enters the Resumed state, it comes to the foreground, and then the system invokes the onResume() callback. This is the state in which the app interacts with the user. The app stays in this state until something happens to take focus away from the app. Such an event might be, for instance, receiving a phone call, the user’s navigating to another activity, or the device screen’s turning off.

When the activity moves to the resumed state, any lifecycle-aware component tied to the activity's lifecycle will receive the `ON_RESUME` event. This is where the lifecycle components can enable any functionality that needs to run while the component is visible and in the foreground, such as starting a camera preview.

When an interruptive event occurs, the activity enters the Paused state, and the system invokes the `onPause()` callback.

If the activity returns to the Resumed state from the Paused state, the system once again calls `onResume()` method. For this reason, you should implement `onResume()` to initialize components that you release during `onPause()`, and perform any other initializations that must occur each time the activity enters the Resumed state.

2. `onPause`

The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving your activity (though it does not always mean the activity is being destroyed); it indicates that the activity is no longer in the foreground (though it may still be visible if the user is in multi-window mode). Use the onPause() method to pause or adjust operations that should not continue (or should continue in moderation) while the Activity is in the Paused state, and that you expect to resume shortly. There are several reasons why an activity may enter this state.

3. `onDestroy()`

`onDestroy()` is called before the activity is destroyed. The system invokes this callback either because:

1. the activity is finishing (due to the user completely dismissing the
   activity or due to finish() being called on the activity), or
2. the system is temporarily destroying the activity due to a
   configuration change (such as device rotation or multi-window mode)

When the activity moves to the destroyed state, any lifecycle-aware component tied to the activity's lifecycle will receive the ON_DESTROY event. This is where the lifecycle components can clean up anything it needs to before the Activity is destroyed.

Have a look here: [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)