# Android Kotlin: Countdown timer inside of my button

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, android-button, countdowntimer

I am looking for a solution to display a countdown timer inside the button that When the number is equal to zero change button color and do something...

Comment: you can make a countdown timer at activity/fragment level, on its onTick method you can check if the value == 0 you can change the text/background or anything about your color
on the other hand if you want to display the time elapsed in the button you will have to set text of the button in onTick callback method of countdown 

val timer = object: CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

}

    override fun onFinish() {...}
}
timer.start()

Above is a sample which runs for 10 seconds and ticks after every second.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902563/7303915. This answer should help you

Answer (score 1):

I made an button that display countdown timer every 1 second. I put the timer object into a function then call it when my button is pressed. Hope this help someone. With this example it counts down from 4 seconds.

```
private fun countdown(){
    object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            otp_resend.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            // do something after countdown is done ie. enable button, change color 
               etc.
             otp_resend.text = "done!"
        }
    }.start()
}
```